# Write code to take a String input from the user, then print all except the first and last letters of the string on one line

Tags: arrays

Enter a string:
glazed
laze

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String s;
   String w;
   System.out.println("Enter a string :");
   s = scan.nextLine();
   w = (s.substring(1,5));
   System.out.print(w);
```

Make sure you remember how string charcters are indexed, and which characters are included when using the substring method.

Comment: Will the input string length vary?

Comment: Thanks for commenting but i already got the answer.